# How to make the width property to work as auto in css

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to set the width as auto in my **css** file. But, i dont know that why the auto property is not being applied to my div. Below is the code:

**cshtml**

```
<div class="bar-steps"></div>
```

**.js**

```
var activityMonth = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
var activityTotalMonth = [];

for (var j = 0; j < activityMonth; j++) {
activityTotalMonth.push(j);
}

$.each(activityTotalMonth, function (i, v) {

var pos = i * 25 + "px";
var div = $('<div>').addClass('counts').css("left", pos);

$(curelement).find('.bar-steps').append(div);
});
```

**.css**

```
.bar-steps {
width: auto;
float: left;
background: #e2e2e2;
border-radius: 4px;
padding: 4px 0 5px 0;
}

.bar-steps .counts {
width: 3px;
height: 3px;
float: left;
background: #999;
border-radius: 50px;
position: absolute;
top: 3px;
}


.bar-steps .counts:last-child {
margin-right: 0px!important;
```

However if I set my width manually in the div column, it work. as below:

```
<div class="bar-steps" style="width:376px"></div>
```

The fiddle is below: this fiddle contains width set as manually. I want it to be set automatically.

http://jsfiddle.net/8q4tco9c/

What am I doing wrong?

Please help!!

Comment: I cannot. As i want the div to work according to the month value. as there can be variation. Sometime it can be 4 months and sometimes 8 and so on..

Comment: remove float:left for .bar-steps

Comment: yes yes i got it .you want to set the width based on the total number of `activityTotalMonth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this line after your `$.each`

here change 25 to your needed width of a month

```
$('.bar-steps').css('width',parseInt(activityTotalMonth.length*25)+'px');
```

and remove `width: auto;` from your css

Comment: glad that i could help

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/8q4tco9c/1/

**JS:-**

```
var activityMonth = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
var activityTotalMonth = [];

for (var j = 0; j < activityMonth.length; j++) {
    activityTotalMonth.push(j);
}


$.each(activityTotalMonth, function (i, v) {
    var pos = 25 + "px";
    var div = $('<div>').addClass('counts').css("margin-right", pos);

    $('.bar-steps').append(div);
});
```

**CSS:-**

```
.bar-steps {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    background: #e2e2e2;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 4px 0 5px 0;
}
.bar-steps .counts {
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    float: left;
    background: #999;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position:relative;
    top:-7px;
}
.bar-steps .counts:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px!important;
}
```

**HTML:-**

```
<div class="bar-steps"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div.bar-steps {
width: auto;
float: left;
background: #e2e2e2;
border-radius: 4px;
padding: 4px 0 5px 0;
```

}

```
div.bar-steps .counts {
width: 3px;
height: 3px;
float: left;
background: #999;
border-radius: 50px;
position:relative;
top:-7px;
```

}

```
div.bar-steps .counts:last-child {
margin-right: 0px!important;
```

}

try this code...